# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery - Hibernate Error

Tags: java, hibernate, sessionfactory, hibernate-session

Above exception has been throwing  While creating a hibernate session factory.

[image]

In application lib folder have hibernate-jpa-2.1-api and javax.persistence.2.1.0. I can able to see the NamedStoredProcedureQuery class in both jar. But I am getting runtime error for classnotfoundexception. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

NamedStoredProcedureQuery class is available in hibernate-jpa-2.1-api jar. But this jar refers some other jar in run time. So I didn't get error in compile time and getting exception during runtime. I just added other hibernated libs through maven repository.Initially i used only hibernate-core. Now artifactIDs  are hibernate-core,hibernate-validator,hibernate-commons-annotations,hibernate-jpa-2.0-api and hibernate-entitymanager.

Answer (score 0):

I have a non-ideal solution. I ended up using hibernate-core 3 (3.6.10) which doesn't throw the same error.

I got this idea from Mario Schwaiger, CodeRanch, for a different, but similar, class not found exception: http://www.coderanch.com/t/509836/ORM/databases/Hibernate-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-javax

Details: I'm doing something slightly different - integrating Hibernate 4 with Struts 1 (instead of Spring), but ran into the same NamedStoredProcedureQuery  class not found problem. Adding hibernate-validator threw different errors. Other things that did not work for me were: adding hibernate-entitymanager, adding javax.persistence, and changing tomcat or eclipse java versions between Java 8 and 7.

You'll need to instantiate the sessionfactory differently between Hibernate 3 and 4.

Hopefully somebody will post a better solution to your Spring problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add hibernate-entitymanager to your classpath.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
```