# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException in spring hibernate integration using maven

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

**step 1:**

> still not getting the exact reason of this exception in my code after
>   searching a lot , In Spring hibernate integration using maven.

**step 2:**
with my one of the controller class with many more controller named *'applicantResultController'* .

**step 3** I had run the same code on another system and after importing this project i get this exception . With my spring version 3.2.3.RELEASE and hibernate version 4.1.9.Final.

**EXCEPTION**-----

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantResultController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.service.ApplicantResultServiceImpl com.controller.ApplicantResultController.applicantResultService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantResultService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.dao.ApplicantResultDaoImpl com.service.ApplicantResultServiceImpl.applicantResultDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'applicantResultDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.ApplicantResultDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
```

you need to add the proper jar file.

You can verify it here:

```
$ wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/persistence/javax.persistence/2.1.0/javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar
$ jar tvf javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar  | grep "NamedStoredProcedureQuery"
   758 Wed Apr 24 12:14:28 AEST 2013 javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exception stacktrace, it seems it's failing because it can't find `NamedStoredProcedureQuery` class:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/NamedStoredProcedureQuery`

Can you try adding [Hibernate API jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final) into the project libraries.

Answer (score 0):

add `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api` and also check all jar you have added in your maven
[read link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247750/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-persistence-namedstoredprocedurequery) also go with this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3524/spring-hibernate-integration-example-tutorial)